# файл jsp не видит значения из сервлета

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

```
***код сервлета:*** 

package servlets;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;


/**
 * Created by Chris_000 on 22.06.2017.
 */

@WebServlet("/s")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.doPost(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        request.setAttribute("loc", Locale.getDefault());

        String varTextA = "Hello World!";
        request.setAttribute("textA", varTextA);
        String varTextB = "It JSP.";
        request.setAttribute("textB", varTextB);


        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

}


***код файла JSP:***

<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p>${textA}</p>
<p>${textB}</p>
${azaza}
<p>БЛИИИННН!!!!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

если не принципиально , сделай web.xml в папке WEB-INF
занеси туда :

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>(полный путь)MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/s</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

потом тоже самое для своего JSP, только там не  / , будет ,что то другое .. поищи .. должно все работать ! нужно прописывать JSP обязательно и все будет видеть

---

Исправьте ваш JSP таким образом :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>webapp</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <c:set var="textB" value="textB"/>
        ${textB}
    </body>
  </html>
```

должен вывести этот кусок : String varTextB = "It JSP.";

или скиньте ваш JSP Servlet и файл pom.xml

еще момент , скачайте .jar файл jstl-1.2.jar  (http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjstl12jar.htm)
и поместите в ваш проект в папку lib или libraries(если в IDEA делаете) короче он должен быть , чтобы работало это <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

---

все я все понял .. я переписал ваш код и у себя запустил все работает.

если ваша задача вывести текст с ИМЕННО с сервлета на JSP страницу !! что очень важно !! то , вам нужно стартовать Сервер НЕ с index.jsp !! а делать старт именно с MyServlet !! скорее всего вы стартуете сразу index.jsp и конечно он ничего не выводит, так как сервлет не запустился еще и он его просто не видит его. стартуйте сервер с сервлета (MyServlet) правой кнопкой и Run on server (не знаю какой средой разработки вы пользуетесь) смысл вы поняли ?

верните ваш код в исходное состояние и пробуйте

Comment: У меня используется сервлет версии 3 или 3 alpha, где это не обязательно. 
Так что я вообще не знаю что делать и возникает уже желание послать всю Java нафиг

Comment: напиши свой JSP . судя по коду должно быть что то вроде :

Comment: так он есть в коде, в самом низу

Comment: а попробуйте , что я описал выше

Comment: еще момент , скачайте .jar файл jstl-1.2.jar  (http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjstl12jar.htm)
и поместите в ваш проект в папку lib или libraries(если в IDEA делаете) короче он должен быть , чтобы работало это <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

Comment: Подключил данную зависимость через maven - не помогло(

Comment: @SashaSan собрал ваши ответы в один. По-прежнему не ясно, что же из этого помогло автору вопроса. Пожалуйста, если вы еще помните, выделите итоговое решение.